# Making faux pretty URL's for one directory online

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I wish to modify .htaccess to be able to go to www.mysite.com/profile instead of www.mysite.com/profile.php, using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However I wish this to only apply to to the main folder, and not a sub folder such as www.mysite.com/newapp, where I will begin writing an app implementing clean URL's with the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^/newapp/ controller.php
```

Is it possible to have two RewriteRule's like that? Can I confine the first one to my home directory?

Answer (score 0):

add new .htaccess file to sub directories and put "RewriteEngine Off" to that.

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

this code will disable rewrite rules on folder which it be

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RewriteCond to restrict the rule to the main folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```